# Reporting Services 2000 server is not recognizing Internet Explorer 8 as up level

Tags: internet-explorer, ssrs, internet-explorer-8

The reports are getting rendered in HTML 3.2 instead of 4.0. Which stops the toolbar from  appearing.

Has anybody managed to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out it is because there is a bug in the asp-net 1.1 framework that causes browsers to be recognized as down-level if there user-agent string is too long.